# Customizing Footer Background Image in Blogger's Simple Template

Tags: css, templates, blogger

I've been trying to customize Blogger's Simple template and have hit a wall in getting the background image for footer-outer to match up - I am still learning CSS and am not sure where the padding on left is coming from or how to get it to completely cover up the repeating background of body-fauxcolumn-outer at the very bottom. Or even if this is the best way to be coding it. Please help!

http://fantasyartofetsy.blogspot.com/

Here's my edited code -

```
.footer-outer {
width: 1000px;
background: url(http://i1192.photobucket.com/albums/aa324/faeteam/fae-bg-bottom.jpg) no-repeat top center;
background-color: #093e60;
```

}

```
.body-fauxcolumn-outer {
background: url(http://i1192.photobucket.com/albums/aa324/faeteam/fae-bg-middle.jpg) center;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems better with the following modification:

```
.content-inner {
    10px 60px 0 10px;
}
```

The background image is now displayed horizontally as intended I guess but there's still text displayed half on the image half on the blue background. Where do you want it to be displayed?

EDIT: maybe also modify that:

```
.footer-inner {
    padding: 80px 15px 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: That! Or it's my daily job ;)

Comment: Hi @FelipeAls - I have a similar problem that I hope you can help me with again. To get my larger footer background to match up on http://aquariann-art.blogspot.com adjusting the content-inner makes post area too big - how can I shrink it? Also, is it possible to move left column about 50px up, and right column about 200px? They, and my line of links above them, move as one unit right now.